# Perl Can't call method "parse_html_string" or unbless reference

Tags: html, perl, parsing

I'm trying to use the module HTML::Grabber to parse html in perl. It works when I just use it in my main process, but it throws me error when I attempt to use it with threading.

Specifically, I got this error,

```
 Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Can't call method "parse_html_string" 
 on unblessed reference at /usr/local/ActivePerl-5.10/site/lib/HTML/Grabber.pm line 79.
```

where the creation of Grabber object.

```
$mech->get($link);
$dom = HTML::Grabber->new(html => $mech->content); #at this point
```

Any idea how to fix this weird problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parse_html_string` method is called on an [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML) parser object.

`XML::LibXML` seems to have mixed support for threads:

- http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-1.78/LibXML.pod#THREAD_SUPPORT

What is probably happening is `HTML::Grabber` is creating the parser object when it is imported by your script in the main thread.  Then you create a child thread, and since `XML::LibXML` does not clone between threads, the object disappears.  You will need to do a runtime load of `HTML::Grabber` with `require` in the thread after it is spawned.

If that is not the case, you will have to boil down your problem to a small example and post the code here.

Comment: I'm not using MS Windows, I'm using MAC OS. Plus, I said it works with single process but not working with Thread..